# permutation of a vector of ints

Tags: c++, vector

I have problems debug this code. Could you please help me with it? Thank you! This code is implementing permutation of a vector of ints. I tried to debug it and found the problem, but I don't know why it is wrong. This code gives me run time error and when I tried to print what are inside vector "cv" after I insert "cur" into cv, it just cannot print any thing, but before insert, "cv"'s contents can be print out. I am confused where I am wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > permutation(vector<int> &v){
  vector<vector<int> > ret; 
  if(v.empty()) {
      return ret;
  }

  if(v.size()==1){
      int cur=v.back();
      v.pop_back();
      vector<int> cv;
      cout<<"cur "<<cur<<endl;
      cv.push_back(cur);
      ret.push_back(cv);
      return ret;
  }
  int cur=v.back();
  v.pop_back();
  vector<vector<int> > temp=permutation(v);
  vector<int>::iterator it;
  cout<<"temp.size() "<<temp.size()<<endl;
  for(int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++){ 
        for(it=temp[i].begin(); it!=temp[i].end(); it++){
            //for(int p=0; p<temp[i].size(); p++) cout<<temp[i][p];
            //cout<<endl;
            vector<int> cv(temp[i]); 
            //for(int p=0; p<cv.size(); p++) cout<<cv[p];
              //cout<<endl;
            cv.insert(it, cur);
            for(int p=0; p<cv.size(); p++) cout<<cv[p];
            cout<<endl;

            ret.push_back(cv);
         }
         vector<int> cv(temp[i]); 
         cv.push_back(cur);
         ret.push_back(cv);
   }
   return ret;
}

int main(){
 vector<int> v;
 v.push_back(1);
 v.push_back(2);
 v.push_back(3);
 v.push_back(4);
 vector<vector<int> > ret=permutation(v);
 for(int i=0; i<ret.size(); i++){
   for(int j=0; j<ret[i].size(); i++) cout<<ret[i][j];
   cout<<endl;

 }

}
```

Comment: Unless this is for something like homework where you need to do everything on your own, you might want to look at `std::next_permutation` and/or `std::random_shuffle`.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I need to implementing permuataion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    for(it=temp[i].begin(); it!=temp[i].end(); it++){
....  

        cv.insert(it, cur);
```

You use iterator from `temp`, to set position within `cv`
Also

```
     for(int i=0; i<ret.size(); i++){
       for(int j=0; j<ret[i].size(); i++) cout<<ret[i][j];
//                                   ^ I believe j meaned
```

Comment: The reason I use iterator is I want to use the insert function of vector, it only allows iterator. cv is another vector which has is the same with temp[i] at the begining and I insert something into it and push it into ret.

Comment: @dianedan Where do you want insert your value? In any case you must use iterator that iterates `cv` to insert into `cv`

Comment: I want to insert value into cv and did use iterator.

Comment: @dianedan if you don't need to insert it at specific index, use `push_back`, if you do need insert it at some index use `cv.insert(cv.begin()+index, cur);` just make sure that it won't go out of bounds by checking that `index<cv.size()`

Comment: it works now, thank you very much! But I cannot understand why the for loop for(it=temp[i].begin(); it!=temp[i].end(); it++) is not working? Before insert, temp[i] actually has the same index as cv's.

Comment: @dianedan `it` is iterator that holds pointer to element in `temp` usage of `it` to set position within `cv` is meaningless since it points somewhere outside of `cv`.

Comment: Oh, I got you! Thank you very much for your help!